# ORDER BY with COALESCE with '~' instead of 'ZZZ' sorts NULL value to the top

Tags: sql-server

My query

```
SELECT COALESCE(MetaClass, 'TOTALS'), COUNT(*) AS [Total], SUM(CASE WHEN ci.ConditionID < 20 OR ci.ConditionID = 29 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS [Still Here], SUM(CASE WHEN ci.ConditionID > 19 AND ci.ConditionID <> 29 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS [Disposed], COUNT(DISTINCT Class) AS [Classes], COUNT(DISTINCT Model) AS [Models]
FROM cmdb_ci_and_status AS ci
INNER JOIN cmdb_model AS m ON m.ModelID = ci.ModelID
INNER JOIN cmdb_class AS c ON c.ClassID = m.ClassID
INNER JOIN cmdb_metaclass AS mc ON mc.MetaClassID = c.MetaClassID
GROUP BY GROUPING SETS ((MetaClass), ())
```

gives a nice table, with a row containing totals of each column. Of course we want the results sorted so we add an 'ORDER BY' clause:

```
ORDER BY MetaClass
```

which orders all MetaClasses alphabetically. However, the row with totals is sorted at the top (due to MetaClass being NULL), which is not what you would want. Therefore you need to tweak the ORDER BY a bit. I have found two ways of doing this:

```
ORDER BY CASE WHEN MetaClass IS NULL 1 ELSE 0 END, MetaClass
```

or:

```
ORDER BY COALESCE(MetaClass, 'ZZZ')
```

Both giving the result I want: the row with TOTALS at the bottom.

Obviously, the first solution is robust, but I rather like the second one. However, suppose someone would add a MetaClass with a name starting with 'ZZZZ', then that would ruin my ordering. To fix that, I tried to come up with a character that is higher in rank than 'Z':

```
ORDER BY COALESCE(MetaClass, '~')
```

but to my surprise, this does not work, and the TOTALS row is placed at the top again.

Can anyone tell me why this fails? And, if possible, how to fix this?

Comment: What collation are you using?

Comment: The solution you "rather like" can't be made to work in all collations, and in fact I suspect can't be made to work at all for *some* collations without being very ugly. There is no "give me a value that's guaranteed to come after all values in this set according to this collation" operation in T-SQL. Note also that string ordering typically does not occur *per character*, but the string as a whole, so you can't even be sure that tacking on a character to an existing string will have the desired effect. That way lies massive headaches, especially when we throw in Unicode. Just don't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A better, and in my opinion, more efficient option than @Larnu's excellent answer, is to order by `GROUPING()` function, this tells us whether the row is a rollup.

It returns 1 for aggregated, and 0 for non-aggregated:

```sql
SELECT COALESCE(MetaClass, 'TOTALS'), COUNT(*) AS [Total], SUM(CASE WHEN ci.ConditionID < 20 OR ci.ConditionID = 29 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS [Still Here], SUM(CASE WHEN ci.ConditionID > 19 AND ci.ConditionID <> 29 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS [Disposed], COUNT(DISTINCT Class) AS [Classes], COUNT(DISTINCT Model) AS [Models]
FROM cmdb_ci_and_status AS ci
INNER JOIN cmdb_model AS m ON m.ModelID = ci.ModelID
INNER JOIN cmdb_class AS c ON c.ClassID = m.ClassID
INNER JOIN cmdb_metaclass AS mc ON mc.MetaClassID = c.MetaClassID
GROUP BY GROUPING SETS ((MetaClass), ())
ORDER BY GROUPING (MetaClass);
```

Comment: This is the most elegant solution! Thanks, learned a lot.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is very simple, a tilda (`~`) has a lower value than your other strings (in the collation you are using). I, for example, am using the SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS collation, and this can be easily demonstrated with the following:

```sql
SELECT CASE WHEN '~' < 'A' THEN 1 END LessThanA,
       CASE WHEN '~' < 'Z' THEN 1 END LessThanZ;
```

Both statements return `1`. [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=a4d96720199bc7cb947a11ddb32623f7). And because it has a lower value, then it is ordered first.

If you want `NULL` values last, explicitly state that with a `CASE` expression (as T-SQL doesn't support `NULLS LAST`/`NULLS FIRST` syntax):

```sql
ORDER BY CASE WHEN YourColumn IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END,
         YourColumn;
```

*If you want to see the order the characters for your collation are sorted in, you can do something like this, which shows that a tilda (`~`) has a sort position of `65`, where a character like `A` is position 143 (in my collation). This gives the order of the characters for characters that can be represented in a `varcar`:*

```sql
WITH N AS(
    SELECT N
    FROM (VALUES(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL))N(N)),
Tally AS(
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) -1 AS I
    FROM N N1, N N2, N N3, N N4)
SELECT T.I,
       CHAR(T.I) AS C,
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY CHAR(T.I)) AS S
FROM Tally T
ORDER BY C;
```

Comment: I am familiar with your solution, as stated in my question. But if the tilde orders below A-Z, then which character orders greater than A-Z? Or is there no such character?

Comment: There are plenty of characters "after" `Z`, @Dandorid , but don't rely on that as it **does** change by collation, order your `NULL` values explicitly.

Comment: `ORDER BY GROUPING()` probably better